# Maximum likelihood estimators for gamma distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I'm having trouble with an exercise about maximum likelihood estimators.

Specifically, the exercise gives me values of a protein which was found in 50 adults. We assumed that the data follow a gamma distribution:

$X \sim \Gamma(r,\lambda)= \frac {\lambda^{r}}{\Gamma(r)}x^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x} $ if $x\ge0$.

It asks me to find the maximum likelihood estimators of parameters $\lambda$ and $r$.

How can I find those parameters given that from the data I have $E(X),Var(X)$?

Comment: The standard recipe: write down the likelihood function, take the logarithm, take the gradient of that with respect to the parameters, set it equal to zero. Doing that here, you readily get that the expected value of the estimated distribution (whatever that is in your parametrization; there are three in common usage and it is not clear which you are using here) is the sample mean. I do not easily see how to find both parameters, however, because the other equation appears to be transcendental.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1510480/321264

Answer (score 3):

We know that $\Gamma(r,\lambda)= \frac {1}{\Gamma(r)}\lambda^{r}x^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x} $ if $x\ge0$.
In this case the likelihood function $L$ is $$\prod_i \Gamma(r,\lambda)_{x_i}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(r)^{n}}\lambda^{nr}x_1^{r-1}x_2^{r-1}...x_n^{r-1}e^{-\lambda T}$$
where $T=x_1+...+x_n$;

By apllying the logaritmic function to $L$ we semplificate the problem so

$$logL=(r-1)\sum_ilogx_i-\lambda T +(nr)log\lambda -nlog(\Gamma(r))$$

and now we must find the point of  max of $logL$, so $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\lambda}= -T+\frac{nr}{\lambda}=0$ which have as solution $\hat\lambda = \frac{nr}{T}$.

With the same method you can obtain the extimation for $r$. (Find $\frac {\partial L}{\partial r}$ and put it equal to $0$).

Comment: yes i agree with you but from the one equation i find that λ=\frac{\widehat{r}}{\widetilde{x}} and from the other  lnr-Γ'(r)/Γ(r)=lnx-x . i have to find numbers not equations...I imagine in this stage i have to use newton-raphson method to find r estimator to find r1 r2 r3 .... until |r4-r3|<10^-4 for example ....i dony know which  r to put in the first equation....sorry for my equations i have to get used latex more....if you have question about the equations i wrote ask me

Comment: the one equation is:  \widehat{ \lambda }=  \frac{r}{ \bar{x} } and the other equation is: \ln( \hat{r} )-\frac{ \Gamma '(r)}{\Gamma (r)} =\ln \bar{x}- \bar{x}

Comment: Maybe you must stimate T with the expected value, the problem give you any information to the the values that each X_i assume?

Comment: no nothing...i can compute μ and σ from the given data but only those....i know that i have to use newton-raphson method for the second equation and after a couple results i have to put r in the first equation but why? and also the first equation has \widehat{r} not r1,r2,....,rn

Comment: In this case i don't know how i can help you, i'm sorry.

Comment: Indeed $\frac{\partial L}{\partial r}$ gives a transcendental equation, even if you know the data $x_i$. One first approximation is to set the variance equal to the sample variance, which would give $r=(\lambda S^{-2})^{1/2}$. This is just the "method of moments" estimator. It is probably not the MLE but it is a place to start your numerical method.

Comment: From the method of moments I have ${{r}_{0}}=\frac{{{\overline{x}}^{2}}}{{{s}^{2}}}$ .Even If I run the newton-rapson method until $\left| {{r}_{n+1}}-{{r}_{n}} \right|<{{10}^{-4}}$ how can I use the ${{r}_{n+1}}$ in my 1st equation which is$\hat{\lambda }=\frac{{\hat{r}}}{{\bar{x}}}$ ?

Comment: To be more certain we have from the method of moments that $\mu =\bar{x}=\frac{{\hat{r}}}{{\hat{\lambda }}}$ and ${{s}^{2}}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50}{({{x}_{i}}-\bar{x}}{{)}^{2}}= \frac{{\hat{r}}}{{{{\hat{\lambda }}}^{2}}}$ . From this 2 equations we have ${{s}^{2}}=\frac{{\bar{x}}}{{\hat{\lambda }}} =>\hat{\lambda }=\frac{{\bar{x}}}{{{s}^{2}}}$and $\hat{r}=\hat{\lambda }\bar{x}=\frac{{{{\bar{x}}}^{2}}}{{{s}^{2}}}$.

Comment: OK, so you have an initial guess for $r$, namely $\frac{\overline{x}^2}{s^2}$, and an initial guess for $\lambda$, namely $\frac{\overline{x}}{s^2}$. If all you have is the sample mean and sample variance then this is the best you can do. If you have the data then you can try to numerically solve the system of two equations using these method of moments values as initial conditions.