# Solve the system of equations in the maximum likelihood estimation of Gamma distribution parameters

Tags: gamma-function, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, polygamma, digamma-function

I'm trying to calculate the two parameters of the `Gamma distribution` by solving the system of two equations obtained by differentiating the `Log-likelihood function` relatively to both parameters as suggested here [Maximum likelihood estimators for Gamma distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1811330/242744).

Here is the `PDF (Probability Density Function)` of the `Gamma distribution` I'm using (similarly to the one given in the link mentioned above):

$$f(x) = \frac {1}{\Gamma(r)}\lambda^{r}x^{r-1}e^{-\lambda x} \quad \text{with} \quad x \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad r, \lambda > 0 $$

where:

- $r$ is the shape (= $\alpha$).
- $\lambda$ is the rate (= $\frac{1}{\beta}$ where $\beta$ is the scale).

And, the `Log-likelihood` to maximize is given by:

$$logL=(r-1)\sum_ilogx_i-\lambda T +(nr)log\lambda -nlog(\Gamma(r))$$

where:

- $T= x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n $

Then I got the following system of two equations from the derivatives of $logL$, for which I'm trying to calculate the roots:

$$ \frac{\partial logL}{\partial \lambda} = -T + \frac{nr}{\lambda} = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial logL}{\partial r} = \sum_ilogx_i + nlog\lambda - n\frac{\partial \log(\Gamma(r))}{\partial r} = 0 $$

Now knowing that $\frac{\partial \log(\Gamma(r))}{\partial r}$ is equal to the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) which can be approximated (according to [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)) with the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), how can I solve the previous system of two equations in order to calculate $(r, \lambda)$?

Comment: Shouldn't that term be $-n\Gamma'(r)/\Gamma(r)$?

Comment: @MPW You're right, I've just corrected the formula.

Comment: Looking at the graph of the Digamma function, I suspect its *slope* may be approximately constant for positive $x>>1$, but not the function itself

Comment: @MPW Indeed the derivative of the `Digamma function` is almost constant for large positive numbers, but does this help to solve the previous equations?

Comment: If so, then you can approximate the Digamma function by $a+bx$ for some choice of $a$ and $b$. I think you are telling me the slope $b$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, not sure what to use for $a$. But just pick a couple of values and make a linear interpolation.

Comment: @MPW Actually, what I said earlier is that for a number $x$: $\psi(x) = -EulerMascheroniConstant + ax$ (according to sympy). This is due to the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function): $\psi(x+1) = \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @MPW Good news, I just noticed that the $f(x) = log(x)$ fits almost perfectly well with samples of the `digamma function` for $0 < x < 100$.

Comment: @MPW The bad news is that if I replace the value of $r$ from the first equation and use $log(x)$ as an approximation for the `Digamma function`, I can't obtain a solution for $\lambda$ in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are approximating that term by a constant, solve the second equation for $\lambda$ and then use it in the first to get $r$.

The approximation removes $r$ from the second equation.

However, I think a constant isn't a very good approximation, is it?